# 301 redirect with query parameters isn't working in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a new website recently uploaded on a domain name and I want to redirect individually all my previous pages to the new ones. (they aren't more than 20)

WHat i've tried to accomplish is the following, but for some reason it isn't working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=16&page=PRICES_SKI_PACKS$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.skibansko.bg/prices-ski-packs/ [L,R=301]
```

Old url: http://skibansko.bg/index.php?id=16&page=PRICES_SKI_PACKS
New url: http://www.skibansko.bg/prices-ski-packs/

It simply is redirecting me to the home page of the new website.

The old website was not on Wordpress and the new one is on Wordpress
The old and the new websites were on the same domain as you can see from the url's.

Probably the WordPress rewriting rules are causing it, you can check them here:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And my whole .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=16&page=PRICES_SKI_PACKS$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.skibansko.bg/prices-ski-packs/ [L,R=301]
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: _“It simply is redirecting me to the home page of the new website”_ – that sounds rather impossible; your code as shown can only redirect to `http://www.skibansko.bg/prices-ski-packs/`, or not redirect anywhere at all. Pretty sure it is your new system that does this redirect.

Comment: It is, yes, because the redirect I've put isn't working. WordPress opens the index.php and ignores the parameters.

Comment: You should do that before the standard WP routing kicks in. Reverse the order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, reversing the order did the work and is now perfectly working!